# IntellijIDEA: Неактивна кнопка Run, Warning: "Method Main is never used"

Tags: java, swing

у меня небольшая программка. Создала класс MainWindow:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainWindow extends JFrame {
    public static void Main(String[] args){
        MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
    }
    public MainWindow(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(320,345);
        setLocation(400,400);
        setVisible(true);
        add(new GameField());
    }
}
```

Но неактивна кнопка Run, а также выданы следующие предупреждения:

```
Class 'MainWindow' is never used
Method 'Main(java.lang.String[])' is never used
Parameter 'args' is never used
Variable 'mw' is never used
```

Скажите, в чем у меня проблема.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Редактированием опции возле кнопки Run "Edit Configurations" и добавлением в Build and Run класса MainWindow

Answer (score 1):

В `public static void main()` main **необходимо** писать с маленькой буквы. Как и все другие названия методов (но для остальных это не столь критично).